# How to load a QML file into a QGraphicsScene in Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2

I tried to load a qml file into a `QGraphicsScene` using this code :

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
QQmlEngine *engine = new QQmlEngine;
QQmlComponent component(engine,"main.qml",QQmlComponent::PreferSynchronous);
qDebug()<<component.errors();
QGraphicsObject *object =
 qobject_cast<QGraphicsObject *>(component.create());
scene->addItem(object);
```

errors() returns nothing and the app output says :

```
QGraphicsScene::addItem: cannot add null item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use QtQuick2 (Qt5's  new version of QtQuick/QML) with QGraphicsScene.  You *need* to use it with QQuickView.

If you need to zoom the QML file to make it fit the QQuickView, just use `QQuickView::setResizeMode` to resize the root object to your view(`QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView`).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast this QObject into a QGraphicsObject. The object instance from QQmlComponent is not a subclass of QGraphicsObject. That's why your cast returns a 0 pointer.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I used code [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-integration.html). any suggestion ?

Comment: I am afraid I have none. I don't think what you want to do, using qtquick2 stuff within QGraphicsScene/View is possible. Worked with qtquick1 (your link), but the architecture of qtquick2 seems to be too different. Can you use QtQuickView?

Comment: I need zooming capabilities for a qml file.