# How I can add a qml object to QGraphicsScene using QtQuick 2.0?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I modify the constructor of DiagramScene in a qt example for see a QML widget but this not work:

```
DiagramScene::DiagramScene(QObject *parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent) {
  QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
  view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
  view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///QML/qml/item.qml"));
  QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
  container->setMinimumSize(view->size());
  container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
  this->addWidget(container);
}
```

QML(The file path is correct!!):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "black"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load a QML file into a QGraphicsScene in Qt5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192968/how-to-load-a-qml-file-into-a-qgraphicsscene-in-qt5)

Comment: I am trying the answer, but this not work for my:                      You can't use QtQuick2 (Qt5's new version of QtQuick/QML) with QGraphicsScene. You need to use it with QQuickView.